# django server not starting after configuring the project to run a sass file which I'm using to style my django app

Tags: python, django, sass, server, saas

I configured my django app named Eshop in my django project so that I can run the Sass file i have but after restarting the server in the terminal, it's bringing an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Eshopcompressor'" I've looked through for the Eshopcompressor but its not there, what next?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I added the compressor to
INSTALLED_APPS =[

]